# AST - Find if object keys have usage

Tags: babeljs

Very very inexperienced with AST parsing, been at it for a day making all rite progress got it working on a single file, but not through imports.

The idea is that i want to tag an object with a comment to flag it for extremely aggressive tree shaking.

In

```
// (object-method.js)
export const ObjectMethods = /*@__PURE__*/ {
    foo: () => "do foo",
    bar: () => "do bar"
}

// index.js
import { ObjectMethods } from "./object-methods";

export const runActions = () => {
    ObjectMethods .bar();
};
```

out (foo is deleted as object key because its never used)

```
// (object-method.js)
export const ObjectMethods = /*@__PURE__*/ {
    bar: () => "do bar"
}

// index.js
import { ObjectMethods } from "./object-methods";

export const runActions = () => {
    ObjectMethods .bar();
};
```

Its basically a glorified "usage" detector, just has to be real basic only support objects declared at top-level scope with the comment.

This is what iv'e got up to but then this only works on usage within a single file....

```
const PURE_IDENTIFIER = "@__PURE__";
export default function() {
    return {
        visitor: {
            ObjectExpression(program) {
                if(!program.node.leadingComments) return;
                if(program.node.leadingComments.some((comment) => comment.value === PURE_IDENTIFIER)) {
                    let objectKeys = program.node.properties.map((prop) => prop.key.loc.identifierName);
                    let found = [];
                    program.parentPath.parentPath.parentPath.parentPath.traverse({
                        Identifier(p) {
                            if(objectKeys.includes(p.node.loc.identifierName)) {
                                found.push(p.node.loc.identifierName);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    let duplicates = found.filter((item, index) => found.indexOf(item) === index && found.lastIndexOf(item) !== index);
                    program.node.properties = program.node.properties.filter((prop) => {
                        /* REMOVES DUPLICATES */
                        return duplicates.includes(prop.key.loc.identifierName)
                    });
                }
            },
        },
    };
}
```

The question is how can i support multifile usage detection and removal - Thanks

Comment: nitpick: you'll need to stop analysis if detect that is getting a property by a mutable variable. For example: `ObjectMethods[userInput]`, so you'll can't remove node inside of `ObjectMethods`.

Comment: Yep dont worry got that part added it yesterday just didn't edit it into here